# Why is kafka returning same data from the topic even after it is read once?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, databricks

This is my first Kafka project (with Spark streaming)
I am trying to read a Kafka topic which is getting data from an upstream source.

They are pushing data into the Kafka topic in the below way:

```
def kafka_ingest(df: DataFrame, kafkaconfig: dict, topic_name: str):
    jaas_config = kafkaconfig['jaas_config'] + \
    f" oauth.client.id='{kafkaconfig['client_id']}'" + \
    f" oauth.client.secret='{kafkaconfig['client_secret']}'" + \
    f" oauth.token.endpoint.uri='{kafkaconfig['endpoint_uri']}'" + \
    " oauth.max.token.expiry.seconds='30000' ;"
    df.write.format('kafka') \
      .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', kafkaconfig['kafka_broker']) \
      .option('kafka.batch.size', kafkaconfig['kafka_batch_size']) \
      .option('retries', kafkaconfig['retries']) \
      .option('kafka.max.block.ms', kafkaconfig['kafka_max_block_ms']) \
      .option('kafka.metadata.max.age.ms', kafkaconfig['kafka_metadata_max_age_ms']) \
      .option('kafka.request.timeout.ms', kafkaconfig['kafka_request_timeout_ms']) \
      .option('kafka.linger.ms', kafkaconfig['kafka_linger_ms']) \
      .option('kafka.delivery.timeout.ms', kafkaconfig['kafka_delivery_timeout_ms']) \
      .option('acks', kafkaconfig['acks']) \
      .option('kafka.security.protocol', kafkaconfig['kafka_security_protocol']) \
      .option('kafka.sasl.jaas.config', jaas_config) \
      .option('kafka.sasl.login.callback.handler.class', kafkaconfig['kafka_sasl_login_callback_handler_class']) \
      .option('kafka.sasl.mechanism', kafkaconfig['kafka_sasl_mechanism']) \
      .option('topic', topic_name) \
      .save()
```

When ingesting data into Kafka, I am using the above method in a foreachBatch method where I also mention the corresponding checkpoint as given below.

```
def write_stream_batches(kafka_df: DataFrame, checkpoint_location: str):
    kafka_df.writeStream \
      .format('kafka') \
      .foreachBatch(join_kafka_streams_po_denorm) \
      .option('checkpointLocation', checkpoint_location) \
      .start() \
      .awaitTermination()

def join_kafka_streams_po_denorm(kafka_df: DataFrame, batch_id: int):
    final_df = kafka_df.some_transformations
    kafka_ingest(kafka_ingest, kafkaconfig, topic_name)
```

I am reading data from the topic as:

```
def extract_kafka_data(kafka_config: dict, topic_name: str, column_schema: str, checkpoint_location: str):
    schema = extract_schema(column_schema)
    jass_config = kafka_config['jaas_config'] \
                  + " oauth.token.endpoint.uri=" + '"' + kafka_config['endpoint_uri'] + '"' \
                  + " oauth.client.id=" + '"' + kafka_config['client_id'] + '"' \
                  + " oauth.client.secret=" + '"' + kafka_config['client_secret'] + '" ;'
    stream_df = spark.readStream \
        .format('kafka') \
        .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', kafka_config['kafka_broker']) \
        .option('subscribe', topic_name) \
        .option('kafka.security.protocol', kafka_config['kafka_security_protocol']) \
        .option('kafka.sasl.mechanism', kafka_config['kafka_sasl_mechanism']) \
        .option('kafka.sasl.jaas.config', jass_config) \
        .option('kafka.sasl.login.callback.handler.class', kafka_config['kafka_sasl_login_callback_handler_class']) \
        .option('startingOffsets', 'earliest') \
        .option('fetchOffset.retryIntervalMs', kafka_config['kafka_fetch_offset_retry_intervalms']) \
        .option('fetchOffset.numRetries', kafka_config['retries']) \
        .option('failOnDataLoss', 'False') \
        .option('checkpointLocation', checkpoint_location) \
        .load() \
        .select(from_json(col('value').cast('string'), schema).alias("json_dta")).selectExpr('json_dta.*')
    return stream_df
```

Every time I display data from the dataframe I see same data returning:
Read 1:

```
df = extract_kafka_data(kafka_config, topic_name, column_schema, checkpoint_location)
display(df)
```

output:

```
+---------+-------+
|dept_name|dept_id|
+---------+-------+
|Finance  |10     |
|Marketing|20     |
|Sales    |30     |
|IT       |40     |
+---------+-------+
```

I have 4 records in my topic which I ingested using the method: `kafka_ingest`. Now that I have read all 4 records, I am expecting the no output if I read the topic again.
Read 2:

```
df = extract_kafka_data(kafka_config, topic_name, column_schema, checkpoint_location)
display(df)
```

output:

```
+---------+-------+
|dept_name|dept_id|
+---------+-------+
|Finance  |10     |
|Marketing|20     |
|Sales    |30     |
|IT       |40     |
+---------+-------+
```

Once I read the data in Read 1, I shouldn't see the same data again as per the offset mechanism in the topic.
But the job is returning the same data as it was for `Read 1`.

Is there something wrong with the way I have setup the `offset strategy` and the usage of `checkpointing` ?
Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here ?
Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: You are setting 'startingOffsets' to earliest so it should be reading from start. you can change that to latest and then it should not read from start.

Comment: If I set the offset to earliest but use checkpoint, doesn't checkpoint be given the priority ?

Comment: What I understand is CheckPoint is specific to spark and offset is specific to kafka so setting offset to earliest you are pulling the data from kafka from start and then checkpointing the whole data every-time but I might be wrong.